# Как можно сконвертировать List в double[] ?

Tags: list, java

Проблема в том, что не знаю как это сделать быстро и просто...
Очень не хочется писать цикл, который перегоняет элементы из листа в массив. Посоветуйте что-нибудь другое.

Comment: > Очень не хочется писать цикл, который перегоняет элементы из листа в массив.

А в чем трудность то? )

Comment: Вообщем-то трудности написать нет никакой. Вот только хотелось бы, чтобы время занимало как можно меньше...

Answer (score 2):

У List есть метод toArray. Но вы не получите double[], только Double[]. Читайте Javadoc :)

Comment: Это-то да, вот только не хочется потом возиться с Double[]...

Answer (score 2):

[List.toArray(T[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))

например в ArrayList реализовано через

[System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)